# Send a string from Arduino to Windows Store App via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal

I am trying to get a Unity3d Windows Store App game to read a string of text that is sent from an Arduino Uno Rev3 over Bluetooth.

Unfortunately, the Windows Store App platform does not allow use of the System.IO.Ports namespace, so I am not sure how to get it to read the Bluetooth data.

Does anybody know how to read data from Bluetooth in a Windows Store App?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a BLE solution based on this example:

https://www.simplicity.be/article/eddy-and-his-stones-diy-arduino-beacon-mobile-apps/

Comment: Links can die...maybe include the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

If your HC-06 has COM-port capabilities, then you can use: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication
there is a sample on Github:

[https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SerialArduino

To find out if your device has COM-port capability on windows 10 go to settings/Bluetooth, pair device and go to more settings, tab com-ports and try to add port. If the list is empty unfortunately  you can not use **Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication APIs** to communicate with an Arduino device.

Another way is to use the Bluetooth GATT protocol for communication.
It allows you to read and write data and subscribe to indicate and notify events.
For this there is also a sample on github:
[https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLEClient

It depends on  your HC-06 what Gatt-services are available but there is most likely a service that can reed and write and get notifications.
Hope this can help you,

Groover

Comment: This week I have got the windows 10 makers update Version 1703 build 1503.11 Now it is possible to create Bluetooth serial with RFCOMM Protocol TD , pairing and connecting not needed any more. You can now add a incoming serial connection for almost any Bluetooth LE device.